# ошибка чтения с COM порта

Tags: c#, com-port

Подскажите в чем может быть дело.
Вылетает ошибка:

> Смещение и длина вышли за границы массива или значение счетчика
>   превышает количество элементов от указателя до конца исходной
>   коллекции.
>
> в System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>      в Telemetria.Hardware.Bluetooth.BluetoothDevice.DataReceivedHandler(Object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) в c:\C#\Telemetria.Net 3.0\src\Hardware\Bluetooth\BluetoothDevice.cs:строка 240
>      в System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.CatchReceivedEvents(Object src, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
>      в System.IO.Ports.SerialStream.EventLoopRunner.CallReceiveEvents(Object state)
>      в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      в System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
>      в System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

при приеме данных из порта

```
_serialPort = new SerialPort
{
    Handshake = Handshake.RequestToSend,
    BaudRate = 115200,
    PortName = BluetoothOptions.COM,
    DataBits = 8,
    StopBits = StopBits.One,
    Parity = Parity.None
};

_serialPort.DataReceived += DataReceivedHandler;  

private void DataReceivedHandler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e) {
    var sp = (SerialPort)sender;
    var inData = new Byte[sp.BytesToRead];
    sp.Read(inData, 0, sp.BytesToRead);
    foreach (var t in inData) {
       _bgLib.Parse(t);
    }
}
```

в строке `sp.Read(inData, 0, sp.BytesToRead);`

ошибка совершенно спонтанна, не могу угадать когда она появится
Пробовал менять настройки порта, эффекта 0

Comment: А может вы читаете из порта больше, чем там в буфере есть?

Comment: Это исключено. Создаю массив длинною с буфер порта var inData = new Byte[sp.BytesToRead]; потом читаю в этот буфер sp.Read(inData, 0, sp.BytesToRead); Вариант sp.Read(inData, 0, inData.Lenght()); ситуации не меняет

Comment: Добавлю, в моем случае КОМ порт это блютуз адаптер, который бесконечно принимает всякую широковещательную хрень

Comment: Может, нужно проверять `EventType`? Если он `SerialData.Eof`, то данных нет.

Comment: Сейчас попробую

Comment: ....нет, не работает

Comment: Я бы вообще не советовал работать с `DataReceived`, на него ругаются практически все. Возьмите лучше несущий `NetworkStream` и читайте из него.

Answer (score 1):

Причина: К тому моменту когда вы взываете

> sp.Read(inData, 0, sp.BytesToRead);

значение

> sp.BytesToRead

уже больше чем размер inData.

Решение:
измените вызов на: `sp.Read(inData, 0, inData.Length)`;

Так же рекомендую установить некоторое вменяемое значение у свойства_serialPort.ReceivedBytesThreshold. В противном случае событие у вас на каждый полученый байт срабатывать будет, что при такой частоте опроса и постоянным потоком данных чревато нехилыми такими фризами